# ethers.js Issues with fetch all text records in a profile

Tags: javascript, node.js, ethereum, ethers.js

I am trying to fetch all ENS text records from a profile and having issues with the logic or possible approaches...

Using ethers.js v6, my current solution is to fetch all the log data and sift through it. The only problem, theres way too many log data that matches the event signature (that stores the text records). The best approach would be to get all transactions using ethers.js that originate with the profile and end at the ENS and then look at the logs using those blockhashes.... But looks like ethers doesnt have a getTransactions() function or anything similar.

What would be the best approach for this?

Current log implementation:

```
const publicResolverContractAddress = '0x231b0Ee14048e9dCcD1d247744d114a4EB5E8E63';


const eventTopic = [
  '0x448bc014f1536726cf8d54ff3d6481ed3cbc683c2591ca204274009afa09b1a1', 
  '0xc0e482f545380f3c76a14db8d5717d205abfdc508449ed2befe6d5427a9d45cd',
  '0x36c0d6cc28ff7763f02401a2d40c3a72c4dfdd8a6b812dfa978274306592721e'
];

let logs = await provider.getLogs({
      address: publicResolverContractAddress,
      fromBlock: '0x1024592',
      toBlock: '0x107D3F5',
      topics: [eventTopic]
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

Good news! There's a cookbook example for this question:
https://docs.ethers.org/v6/cookbook/ens/

Bad news, they're taking your exact model of traversing all logs.
For a more efficient approach, you'll need to use something like ens.js or ENS subgraph.

In case the documentation changes, here's the current version:

```
import { ethers } from "ethers";
import { MulticallProvider } from "@ethers-ext/provider-multicall";

async function getTextRecords(_provider, name) {
  // Prepare a multicall-based provider to batch all the call operations
  const provider = new MulticallProvider(_provider);

  // Get the resolver for the given name
  const resolver = await provider.getResolver(name);

  // A contract instance; used filter and parse logs
  const contract = new ethers.Contract(resolver.address, [
    "event TextChanged(bytes32 indexed node, string indexed _key, string key)"
  ], provider);

  // A filter for the given name
  const filter = contract.filters.TextChanged(ethers.namehash(name));

  // Get the matching logs
  const logs = await contract.queryFilter(filter);

  // Filter the *unique* keys
  const keys = [ ...(new Set(logs.map((log) => log.args.key))) ];

  // Get the values for the keys; failures are discarded
  const values = await Promise.all(keys.map((key) => {
      try {
          return resolver.getText(key);
      } catch (error) { }
      return null;
  }));

  // Return a Map of the key/value pairs
  return keys.reduce((accum, key, index) => {
      const value = values[index];
      if (value != null) { accum.set(key, value); }
      return accum;
  }, new Map());
}

// Example usage
(async function() {
  const provider = new ethers.InfuraProvider();
  console.log(await getTextRecords(provider, "ricmoo.eth"));
})();
```